# hangs on git submodule update

Tags: git, github

installing pupy on kali 2016.2 following by official readme.md

clone pupy from https://github.com/n1nj4sec/pupy.git

```
git clone https://github.com/n1nj4sec/pupy.git
```

change directory

```
cd pupy
```

and then:

```
git submodule init
```

when updating submodule

```
git submodule update
```

it hangs on

```
Cloning into '/root/pupy/pupy/external/LaZagne'...
```

i wait for 2 hours but nothing happend,try again but same results.

what cause to fail submodule update.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it didn't hang, but just slow. Try `--progress` option,

```
git submodule update --progress
```

I found this tip via another SO question, 
[git submodule update --init --recursive hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823070/git-submodule-update-init-recursive-hangs)