# git submodule update --init --recursive hangs

Tags: git, clone

When I type `git submodule update --init --recursive` in order to recursively cloned submodules, it starts to say `cloning...` and then proceeds to do nothing... just hangs.

One apparent fix is getting the paths and repos from the .gitmodule files, navigation to the path they prescribe, and `git clone` them each manually.

Another apparent fix is Cntr-Z to break the action, delete the `.git` files that are produced by the --init clause, and trying again. It seemly works.

I seem to have a broken result however.

My main question is: is how to get `git submodule update --init --recursive` working property, without hanging?

Has others come across this before?

Comment: How long have you waited? It's possible the repo it's trying to clone is very large or something. See if there's network activity.

Comment: 5 - 10 minutes. The thing is, when I break the action, and delete the .git files from the target paths and try again, it begins in a few seconds.

Comment: What about disk activity? if it's a lot of submodules or the hdd has a lot of errors, that could also cause that kind of very long delay with apparently nothing happening.

Answer (score 94):

By default, updating submodules doesn't show progress. And since many Git repos will have a relatively slow download, this can cause the appearance of hanging (and it's happened to me multiple times).

To make sure this isn't just a case of a large, slow download, run the update command with the `--progress` option.

`git submodule update --init --recursive --progress`

Comment: `--progress` is supported since `v2.11.0`

Comment: Also, if it takes long I suggest adding `--depth 1`

Comment: Thank you, that was the case for me.

Comment: `--progress` does not show any difference for me with `git submodule update --remote --init --progress`